# Form key => value inverted since symfony 3, is it possible to overwrite it ?

Tags: symfony

Since Symfony3, the key -> value in 'choices' form is flipped. I try to upgrade a very big project to symfony3 and it would be very difficult for me to flip all the key values.

Is it possible to overwrite the default behaviour of symfony forms to use the old way ?

For example if I have a lot of code like this

```
private static $MAP_MINUS = [
    self::GENTLEMAN => 'm.' ,
    self::MADAME => 'mme.',
];
```

I would have to invert it

```
private static $MAP_MINUS = [
    'm.' => self::GENTLEMAN ,
    'mme.' => self::MADAME,
];
```

But I don't want to because there are way too much arrays in the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually set the 'choices_as_values' option of your form class to false. This only works until symfony4 because the option itself was deprecated with sf3. 
Before they deprecated it they switched the default value to `true` which is the reason your arrays are flipped now.

```
$form->add('status', 'choice', array(
   'choices' => array(
       'Enabled' => Status::ENABLED,
       'Disabled' => Status::DISABLED,
       'Ignored' => Status::IGNORED,
   ),
   // choices_as_values defaults to true in Symfony 3.0
   // and setting it to anything else is deprecated as of 3.0
   'choices_as_values' => true,
   // important if you rely on your option value attribute (e.g. for JavaScript)
   // this will keep the same functionality as before
   'choice_value' => function ($choice) {
       return $choice;
   },
));
```

Comment: I guess there is no global solution so ... I think I will not set choices_as_values to false as it will be deprecated in version 4. I will array_flip the dynamics arrays and functions calls, and if it is static I will change manually.